# How to just fill time into text field in edit form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In migrate :

```
t.time :time_from
```

=> in postgress, time_from column is type: ***time without time zone***

When i add new data:
=> time_from = ***08:00:00***

When i get in edit :

```
@post = Post.find([params[:id]])
```

In form:

[image]

But i just want to show time => 08:00
I tried like this, but it does not working.

```
@post = Post.find([params[:id]])
@post.time_from = Time.parse(@post.time_from.strftime("%I:%M%p"))
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use `strftime`, use just "%I:%M":

```
@post.time_from.strftime("%I:%M")
```

Or you can also use `to_s` plus `:time`:

```
@post.time_from.to_s(:time)
```

---

Date, DateTime and Time `to_s` methods are aliases for [`to_formatted_s`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Palma !